# Access GSuite user mailboxes using admin credentials

Tags: c#, gmail-api, google-workspace

Can I access Gsuite domain users mailbox using admin credentials of that account.
Currently I am using service account and able to read mailboxes, but can the same thing be done using admin credentials without service account.

Note: I am using Gmail API to read mailbox

Answer (score 1):

You have to use service account in order to access domain wide user's data. Gmail API is scoped to individual users, even if you authorize with the domain super admin you will get access only to his personal data.

Please refer:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation, 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings.